# Groupby and selecting max row within groupby result

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Is it possible to groupby and sort results within each groupby result in Python/Pandas?

Trying to find the top Genere in each year in below given data.Tried a lot using groupby and sort but no luck.

```
Input::

release_year    Genere      Count

1997            Action      46
1997            Adventure   7
1997            Animation   2
1997            Children's  12
1997            Comedy      73
1997            Crime       22
1997            Documentary 6
1997            Drama       81
1997            Horror      6
1997            Mystery     5
1997            Romance     15
1997            Sci-Fi      1
1997            Thriller    9
1997            War         1

1998            Action      12
1998            Adventure   2
1998            Comedy      24
1998            Crime       6
1998            Documentary 2
1998            Drama       21
1998            Film-Noir   2
1998            Horror      3
1998            Romance     4
1998            Thriller    1


Expected Output:

release_year    Genere      Count
1997            Drama       81
1998            Comedy      24
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```py
df_res = df.groupby(['release_year','Genere'])['Count'].sum().reset_index()
indexs = []
for year in df_res['release_year'].unique():
    df_temp = df_res[df_res.release_year==year]
    indexs += list(df_temp[df_temp['Count']==df_temp['Count'].max()].index)
df_res = df_res.loc[indexs]
```

I don't use 'sort()'. I use 'max()' instead.

Comment: nope, not working, it resulted in following: 1998 Thriller 1, which is not correct.

Comment: yes, that's wrong...I made some mistakes. In the loop, it should be

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
df=df.sort_values("Count", ascending=False)

df.groupby("release_year").first()
```

Outputs:

```py
              Genere  Count
release_year
1997           Drama     81
1998          Comedy     24
```